# addClass to checked radiobutton and removeClass from not:checked radio button by CLASS

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('label').click(function() {
         var total = 0;

          $('.option:checked').each(function() {
              total += Number($(this).data('number'));   
              total = total.toFixed(2); 

          });

              $('#ship_total').text(total);

                var sub_total = <?php echo $this->cart->total(); ?>;

                var ship_total = ($("#ship_total").text());

                var final_total = parseFloat(sub_total) + parseFloat(ship_total);

                final_total = final_total.toFixed(2);

            $('#new_total').text(final_total);

        $('.option:not(:checked)').removeClass('shippingSet');
        $('.option:checked').addClass('shippingSet');
      });
    });
</script>
```

Simple enough.. I want to addClass to checked radio and removeClass from a not checked radio. Radio have a class named `option`

I'm able to addClass using `$(this).addClass('shippingSet')` but I don't know how to remove it. Can someone tell me the proper way to add/remove class please? Thanks.

## HTML

```
<label><input type="radio" name="ship" class="option" data-number="<?php echo $shipTotal['Ground']; ?>" value="S1"/> Ground <b>$<?php echo $shipTotal['Ground']; ?></b></label>
```

## DEMO -->

http://jsfiddle.net/vdgAQ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/vdgAQ/2/

In your original fiddle, you added the class to the radio button itself which will not affect the styles of the labels, and the radio button itself has no text colour to change or bg colour to change so you won't see any difference. I only added

```
$('.option').parent().removeClass('shippingSet');
$('.option:checked').parent().addClass('shippingSet');
```

this will add the class to the parent which is "label" and it will affect the txt and bg of the label which contains the visible text

Comment: yes that is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please explain how this works. I gave you the checkmark! thank you

Comment: I updated the answer to explain, you should always use firebug to inspect element to see if the jquery is working. As this issue was caused by css

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. :) I was pulling my hair out just doing `$('.option').removeClass('shippingSet');` and I wasn't getting any errors. All along all I needed was `.parent()` .. But I also tried `$('label').removeClass('shippingSet');` and that didn't work... Wouldn't `label` be the `parent()` ?

Comment: label is the parent, but just label would not work since you don't know if the radio inside is checked or not so the code you have now is good

Answer (score 1):

Hard to help without seeing the HTML, but you could try this:

```
// remove class from all option elements
$('.option').removeClass('shippingSet'); 

// add class only to elements that satisfy your criteria
$('.option:checked').addClass('shippingSet');
```

Comment: why would it not work? you remove the class from all option then add to the ones that is checked

Comment: there is something else wrong with your code, check for errors, see here http://jsfiddle.net/PATa4/

Comment: The error is elsewhere in your code - see: http://jsfiddle.net/vdgAQ/4/ (where I commented out everything from your demo save the essentials and the above solution - my solution and Sushanth's also work under these conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate thru all the elements and add and remove class checking the `:checked` attribute.

```
 $('.option').each(function(){
         if( $(this).is(':checked')){
             $(this).addClass('shippingSet');
         }
         else{
             $(this).removeClass('shippingSet');
         }
    });
```

Comment: I put your code in the space where mine was. It isn't working. Added the HTML here.. What is the problem?

Comment: Just a background color and font-color -- see the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/vdgAQ/1/

Comment: @fabio you NEED to use firebug. The styles on the checked radio will NOT show up, at least not on FF 11, if you want to change the text colour and background you need to add class on the label not the radio button itself

Comment: I am using firebug-- the console indicate no errors. Ok so I tried replacing `.option` with `label` but it still isn't working. Did you see my demo?

Comment: see my fiddle in my answer, I added lines to your fiddle near the bottom. I left the addClass to the radio button but if the fiddle is what you are looking for, then you can take that line out as well. If you tried the addClass code using firebug you can see the classes are being added correctly, but your css styles is the one that is not working

Comment: @Huangism yes I am using firebug and console wasn't showing any errors in the JS. How did you determine the issue in firebug?

Comment: @fabio you can inspect element with firebug and see when the class gets added/removed so it was obvious that the jquery was working